# Need to get the Least Frequent element of a 2D array

Tags: java

```
int curr = 0;
int cnt;
String element = values[0][0];
int numberRepeats = 0;//cnt-counter,what's the element ,how many times it's repeated

     for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {//those two for's are for the current element
            cnt = 0;//counter is nullified
            for (int j2 = i; j2 < values.length; j2++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < values[j2].length; k++) {//and those two are the compared element
                    if (values[i][j] == values[j2][k]) {//if the current element is the same as the compared element,increase counter
                        cnt++;                        
                    }
                }

            if (cnt >numberRepeats) {//after the compared element is done comparing and the number of repeats of the current element is more then the lastly checked element
                element = values[i][j];//we get the element ,and how many times it's repeated
                numberRepeats = cnt;
            }
        }
    }
}    
System.out.println();
System.out.println("The most popular item is: "+element+". Number sold:"+numberRepeats);`
```

This is what I currently get:

```
houseShampoo    meatPork    dairyCream  wheatBread  wheatCrackers   
houseShampoo    houseShampoo    houseDetergent  meatPork    dairyYogurt 
meatLamb    dairyMilk   dairyCream  meatPork    houseShampoo    
wheatCookies    meatLamb    dairyYogurt wheatCereal wheatBread  
meatLamb    dairyMilk   wheatCookies    wheatCrackers   wheatPasta  

The most popular item is: houseShampoo. Number sold:4
```

This is what I want to get:

```
The least popular item is: wheatPasta. Number sold:1
```

But I don't know how to change the condition in the `if`  statement to give out the least frequent element instead of most popular

Comment: what's the problem you're having? what exactly is preventing you from continuing?

Comment: You didn't ask any question

Comment: Need to get the Least Frequent element of a 2D array

Comment: what's the problem you're having?

Comment: dont know how to change the condition in the if statement to give out the least frequent element instead of most popular

Comment: Can you use collections instead?

Comment: when you run the code what output do you get?

Comment: houseShampoo meatPork dairyCream wheatBread wheatCrackers
houseShampoo houseShampoo houseDetergent meatPork dairyYogurt meatLamb dairyMilk dairyCream meatPork houseShampoo
wheatCookies meatLamb dairyYogurt wheatCereal wheatBread
meatLamb dairyMilk wheatCookies wheatCrackers wheatPasta

The most popular item is: houseShampoo. Number sold:4

Comment: makes a [10][5] 2d array out of contents in text file at random with duplicates. im able to get the frequent element but i need the least

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to find the minimum number of repeats, start of your initial value with the maximum value:

```
int numberRepeats = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

and when an item is found with a smaller number of repeats, replace it:

```
if (cnt < numberRepeats) {
    element = values[i][j];
    numberRepeats = cnt;
}
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I choosed different approach using Map I hope it helps :)

```
int dimension = 3;
    int sold = 0;
    String product = "";
    Map<String,Integer> productsSoldAndCount = new HashMap<>();
    String[][] elements = new String[3][3];
    elements[0] = new String[]{"houseShampoo","meatpork","dairyCream"};
    elements[1] = new String[]{"houseShampoo","bread","cookies"};
    elements[2] = new String[]{"meatpork","meatpork","meatpork"};

    for(var tmpArray : elements){
        for(var tmpString : tmpArray){
            if(!productsSoldAndCount.containsKey(tmpString)){
                productsSoldAndCount.put(tmpString,1);
            }else{
                productsSoldAndCount.put(tmpString,productsSoldAndCount.get(tmpString) + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    for(var resultPair : productsSoldAndCount.entrySet()){
        if(resultPair.getValue() > sold){
            sold = resultPair.getValue();
            product = resultPair.getKey();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The most popular item is: " + product + " Sold: " + sold);
```